# How does breaking away from a larger nation effect the economy

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, international-trade, agriculture

I am working on making a fictional world, and I really want to make the economics realistic, so I decided to come here to ask questions. The context is that a large nation went through a large civil war which eventually resulted in breaking into smaller nations.

How exactly would these smaller nations be effected by this, and how it can be fought. As I have it, they were put in jeopardy via losing a large amount of agriculture land, thus reducing their agricultural production, further harmed by a far smaller population and lesser production of other goods due to the increased importance of agriculture. It also cost a lot for reperations after the war.

For the first part, how realistic is it that this is what would happen in this situation? What other things should I be taking into account?

The second question is about how this would be solved. As I have it written down now, there was a process of debasement in order to increase the money which is in circulation by making gold coins an alloy. Which caused inflation. And then to help combat this inflation they began lowering interest rates and trying to establish stable international trade, and changing the taxation system to take into account land productivity.

I intentionally made the first part of reform be to make the economy undergo inflation, taking influence from Diocletian's reform. But I feel not as sure about the manner in which this was fixed, even though I did some research on it. I want to ask more knowledgeble people on how reasonable this response to inflation is, and if it would actually help.

I know it is a very wide question, but I at least want to be given some tips to be guided in the right direction on the economy of nations after breaking away from a larger one, and how to fight inflation.

Comment: Have you considered looking at historical examples instead? E.g.; Ireland, United States of Central America?

Comment: Yes, but I am not exactly sure how to find more in-depth articles on the specifics. Like, I can't find a good article on the United States of Central America economy, just the economy of modern Central America as a whole.